# How can lsblk and fdisk show different sizes for the same partition?

Tags: partition, virtualbox, lvm, fdisk, lsblk

I am running a virtualbox VM and I can see that the size of /dev/sda2 is being shown differently in the two outputs. Also, in the output of fdisk, /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda5 seem to be overlapping

```
~$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 29.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  9.5G  0 part /

~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8f66391d

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1050623  1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 20969471 19916802  9.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 20969471 19916800  9.5G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sda2` partition is a container partition. Its format is very similar to the disk's [Master Boot Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (MBR) and is known as [Extended boot record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) (EBR), itself occupying one of the four possible primary partition slots. It exists to overcome this historical limitation of 4 partitions in the MBR. It includes inside itself extended partitions (which are displayed starting from partition 5 in Linux) and are linked: each further extended partition also has an EBR with two entries: one to reference the partition's data itself, and one to reference the next extended partition's EBR if any. All extended partitions (so here `sda5`) are *inside* their container partition (here `sda2`), and thus fdisk will always report overlapping blocks.

From the [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)'s point of view it uses all the space reserved for adding extended partitions inside it and thus its size has to be greater than the size of all the extended partitions.

From the point of view of the kernel API reporting to userspace and thus `lsblk`, partition 2 is just a glue partition displayed as a courtesy and that should not be tampered with. The data size reported is only the EBR overhead, here 1K, else reading or writing (which is already bad as it can destroy the initial link to all extended partitions within) to partition 2 would also allow reading or writing to partition 5. It could even have been chosen to report a size of 0, it wouldn't matter much. This is different from the handling of `sda` itself which represents the whole disk. When you consider that further extended partitions are linked from each previous extended partition's EBR, this makes sense: their internal EBR isn't even made available, only their actual data is seen.

You should consider using [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitioning instead of MBR/EBR partitioning: it's a modern partition scheme which is much saner and doesn't have such limitations and workarounds. Or you can also choose [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) in one (primary, no need for extended then) partition: this too is a form of container for partitioning blocks at a different abstraction layer, and provides a lot of features.